# change uicollectionview numberofsection when previous value clicked

Tags: swift, collectionview

I'm trying to show the list of variable carmaker in collection view at first then it will change the list into variable Honda when users click on Honda from the first collection view. every time i ran the code from below it give me an error "fatal error: Index out of range" the error come from 
`cell.title.text = Honda[indexPath.row]` i do not understand why because it has the same value (4) with `Honda.count`

```
var selectedrow = 0
var choice1 = ""
var choice2 = ""

// car make
var carmake = ["Honda","Toyota","AUDI","Bentley","BMW","Mercedez","Buick","Cadillac","KIA","Chevrolet","Corvette","Dodge","FIAT","Ford","GMC","Hyundai","Infiniti","Jaguar","JEEP","LandRover","LEXUS","Mazda","Nissan","RAM","Porsche","Scion","Volkswagen"]
// car model
var Honda = ["Oddyssey","Civic","Fit","Adam"]


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch choice1 {
    case "Honda":
        let hon = Honda.count
        print(hon)
        return Honda.count
    default:
        print("default")
        return carmake.count
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = viewcontrol.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! jobtypeCollectionViewCell
    switch choice1 {
    case "Honda":
        //let number = Honda[indexPath.row]
        //print(number)
        cell.title.text = Honda[indexPath.row]
    default:
        cell.title.text = carmake[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedrow = indexPath.row

    switch carmake[selectedrow] {
    case "Honda":
        print("honda")
        choice1 = "Honda"
        print(choice1)
    default:
        print("none selected")
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you reload the collection view?

Comment: i read your comment and try to put self.collectionView.reloadData() after `case "Honda":` both in numberofsection and cellforitematindexpath functions but i still get the same error

Comment: You should not reload the data in those methods. where did you originally place it?

Comment: i did not have `self.collectionView.reloadData()` before. where should i place it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reload the data when you change the data source, in your case at the end of the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedrow = indexPath.row

    switch carmake[selectedrow] {
    case "Honda":
        print("honda")
        choice1 = "Honda"
        print(choice1)
    default:
        print("none selected")
    }
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sam. You Save my life :)

Answer (score 0):

It's going out of range because arrays are zero indexed, meaning your array with 4 items in it are index 0, 1, 2, 3.  There is no item at index 4, as that'd be the 5th item in the Honda array.

Comment: by 4 i meant there are 4 values within that array. both honda[indexpath.row] and honda.count have 4 items.